# How can I select a RadioButton when a TextBox is selected?

Tags: asp.net

I have a `TextBox` next to a `RadioButton`, and when someone selects the `TextBox` it should set the associated `RadioButton` as Selected.

I was using this code until I noticed it only worked for Chrome:

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="SomeGroup" ID="rbOption3" />
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="rbOption3">
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Pay other amount" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOtherAmount" CssClass="money-text" />
    <div class="align-with-radiobutton small-text">
        The minimum amount for web payments is <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMinPayment" />. If you are looking to pay a lower
        amount, please <a href="Contact.aspx">contact us</a> and speak with a representative.
    </div>
</asp:Label>
```

[image]

It behaves differently in all 3 major browsers

**IE:** Selection does not change at all when TextBox is selected

**FireFox:** Selection changes on `MouseUp`, which means anytime you select the TextBox, the focus will change to the RadioButton, which makes it seem like the TextBox is not selectable

**Chrome:** Works fine since the selection changes on `MouseDown`

My requirement is that users can select any part of the Text, or the TextBox, and it will select the Radio Button.

How can I select an associated RadioButton whenever a TextBox gains focus, either from mouse or keyboard navigation?

**Edit**

The solution posted by [rsbarro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9318763/302677) works for IE and Chrome, however it is still failing for FireFox. When you select the TextBox in FireFox, the RadioButton steals focus on MouseUp, which makes it look like the TextBox cannot be selected.

I tried using some jQuery, however the `.changed()` and `.focus()` don't get fired when selecting the TextBox (they get fired when selecting the Label though), and I can't seem to stop the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach worked for me in the latest versions of IE, Firefox, and Chrome:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectRadio3() {
        var rb = document.getElementById('<%= rbOption3.ClientID %>');
        rb.checked = true;
    }

    function selectOtherAmount() {
        var txt = document.getElementById('<%= txtOtherAmount.ClientID %>');
        txt.focus();
    }
</script>

<asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="SomeGroup" ID="rbOption3" onclick="javascript:selectOtherAmount()" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtOtherAmount" Text="Pay other amount" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOtherAmount" onfocus="javascript:selectRadio3()" CssClass="money-text" />
<div class="align-with-radiobutton small-text" onclick="javascript:selectOtherAmount()">
    The minimum amount for web payments is <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMinPayment" />. If you are looking to pay a lower
    amount, please <a href="Contact.aspx">contact us</a> and speak with a representative.
</div>
```

I associated the `Label` with the `TextBox`, and I added javascript to set the `checked` property of the `RadioButton` when the `TextBox` gets the focus. I also added and `onclick` event on the `RadioButton` to set the focus to the `TextBox`.

**EDIT**
Using your original HTML and adding a little javascript worked for me as well. I added an `onclick` event to the `RadioButton` to set the focus to the `TextBox`, and an `onfocus` event on the `TextBox` to set the `checked` property of the `RadioButton`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectRadio3() {
        var rb = document.getElementById('<%= rbOption3.ClientID %>');
        rb.checked = true;
    }

    function selectOtherAmount() {
        var txt = document.getElementById('<%= txtOtherAmount.ClientID %>');
        txt.focus();
    }
</script>

<asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="SomeGroup" ID="rbOption3" onclick="javascript:selectOtherAmount();" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="rbOption3">
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Pay other amount" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOtherAmount" CssClass="money-text" onfocus="javascript:selectRadio3();" />
    <div class="align-with-radiobutton small-text">
        The minimum amount for web payments is <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMinPayment" />. If you are looking to pay a lower
        amount, please <a href="Contact.aspx">contact us</a> and speak with a representative.
    </div>
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: I suppose I shouldn't have tried to simplify my code... I've updated my question to include an extra bit of text which gets displayed below the offending TextBox. I need to be able to select any part of the text, or the TextBox, to select the radio button.

Comment: You could just wrap the text in a div and add an onclick event for the div as well. Relying on javascript might not be preferable, but I just don't think the browsers are all going to play nice with the `TextBox` inside the `Label`. I updated my answer with the `onclick` on the div, it worked fine for me in my test code.

Comment: I suppose I could use that... it's not quite the same though. For example, it doesn't highlight the RadioButton when you hover over it. I was hoping there was some way to keep the labels associated with the RadioButton and have the TextBox working.

Comment: @Rachel: Please check the update to my answer. I left the HTML the same as what you posted in the question and just added a couple javascript events. I am seeing the RadioButton highlight when any of the elements are hovered over. Since it might matter, my doctype is XHTML transitional. Also, when I try to validate the XHTML, it fails because apparently for validation purposes you're not allowed to have a `<div>` inside a `<label>`, might want to switch that to a `<span>` with `display:block`.

Comment: It works for IE and Chrome, but I am still having the problem with FF where selecting the `TextBox` selects the `RadioButton` on `MouseUp`, which makes it seem that the TextBox cannot be selected. I'm testing with FF8

Comment: Strange, I can't reproduce that behavior on FF8. Did you add the onclick event to the radio button?

Comment: I didn't because I want this to work with keyboard navigation as well as mouse navigation. Adding the click event does work for clicking the Box, but not for keyboard navigation.

Comment: Actually, I got it working by using a `.focus()` event on the `TextBox` to select the `RadioButton` in addition to a `.focus()` event on the `RadioButton` to select the `TextBox`. Thank you :)

Comment: Cool, glad you got it to work! And I agree, `focus` sounds like a better event to use in this case than `click`.

Answer (score 0):

rsbarro's answer is correct.

However, if you are using jquery, then here is how it do it:
http://jsfiddle.net/vg8gU/3/

The advantage with jquery is that you don't have to worry about different browsers. It 'just works' on all browsers.

Comment: That only works with mouse navigation. It doesn't work with keyboard navigation, such as tabbing to the TextBox. I am also unable to get rsbarro's answer to work with FireFox

Comment: That was a easy thing to do. Just replace the .click function to .focus. Checkout http://jsfiddle.net/vg8gU/4/
I've added another textbox just to let you tab to the actual textbox where your want your .focus method to trigger !

Comment: It looks hackish though... for example, hovering over the Text doesn't highlight the RadioButton like it should and the cursor is different. I also have to remember to add the click event to any text that is part of the RadioButton (your fiddle only has the click event on half of it). I got it working with rsbarro's help though. I ended up with two focus events, one on the TextBox to select the radio, and one on the RadioButton to focus the TextBox.